# Node Webkit - How to force URL in loaded iframe page to open users default browser

Tags: iframe, webkit

Using Node webkit for some school related software. The software opens some URL's from external servers and do have access to those external iframed pages.

Is there any tags (maybe in href areas) that can be placed into loaded iframe page to force URL to open in users default browser?

Do not want the URL's opening in new node webkit window.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to open links inside iframe in default browser

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
$("#banner iframe").on("load", function(){
    var iframe = $(this).contents();
    iframe.find("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        gui.Shell.openExternal(link);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for input @aimadnet. My issue is I need code that works on page being iframed. Was hoping for some trick that forced links via a href tag or along those lines.

Comment: First u need to add your iframe link to node-remote (package.json) to get access to require function, then add a onclick function on iframe links and use this gui.Shell.openExternal(link); to open them on default browser

Comment: Thanks again! THink you got me on the right track:)